# Cmder bash script executing

Tags: windows, bash, conemu, cmder

I created basic script in Windows.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello
```

I am using Cmder, ConEmu derivative. I tried to change the priviliges with chmod, but they are the same. I don't know how can I execute this script. Normal Linux way, which is: ./hello.sh does not work, and typing just hello.sh makes Windows try to open it, which is bad, since I want it in console. How to execute this script in ConEmu/Cmder?

Comment: Windows does not support the `#!` line, so you need to execute the program, e.g. `bash hello.sh` (as you can in Linux), or change the file association for the `.sh` extension - see the `stat` and `file` commands.

Comment: Thank you, that will do.

Answer (score 17):

I've noticed you can run `bash` from *cmder*. So I could do it like:

```
> bash
$ ./yourScript.sh
```

or simpler

```
> cat yourScript.sh | bash
```

Disclaimer: New to *cmder* (just downloaded it) and Linux myself.

Answer (score 12):

It works just like on Unix shells

```
sh path/to/your/script.sh
```

Comment: This worked best for me - sh runs the script in your current environment (e.g. conda environment) while bash opens a new shell.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me: I'm on Windows 11 and wasn't able to run "bash myscript.sh" anymore because I kept receiving errors on part of the script that were working before.

Answer (score 11):

On my own instance of Cmder, `bash [filename]` works just fine, and I believe much simpler:

```
C:\Users\Conor O'Brien
λ type test.sh
echo Hello

C:\Users\Conor O'Brien
λ bash test.sh
Hello
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be able to run the script by simply typing its name, a workaround is to create an alias and put it into your `.bashrc` such as:

```
alias scriptName="bash /pathToTheScript/yourScript.sh"
```

Or you can source a script inside your `.bashrc` and make it available through a function:

```
source /pathToTheScript/yourScript.sh
```

where the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
function your_function()
{
yourCode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have time jump to **The conclusion** below:

TL:DR: Here my toying with "Cmder > bash" on Windows to create a Global script:

I've created a external script:

```
a@DESKTOP /c/Scripts/
λ vi test.sh
```

with the content

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Can you see me now?'
```

it can be executed from the same folder:

```
a@DESKTOP /c/Scripts/
λ ./test.sh
Can you see me now?
```

on creating a simbolink link:

```
λ ln -s /c/Portables/Scripts/GlobalesBash/test.sh /bin/mytest
```

it seems to work fine calling it with just the name:

```
λ mytest
Can you see me now?
```

but if the original file gets modified:

```
λ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Yes, I see you'
```

the changes are not reflected using the link:

```
λ mytest
Can you see me now?
```

**The conclusion:**

so the best option is creating the script directly on the folder /bin:

```
λ cd /bin
λ vi aloha
λ cat aloha
echo 'aloha!!!'
```

and `#!/bin/bash` isn't even necessary with Cmder on Windows, and it gets executed successfully from everywhere in the Cmder bash:

```
λ cd /c
a@DESKTOP /c
λ aloha
aloha!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your own `.sh` files into `$CMDER_ROOT/config/profile.d/*.sh` directory, as the docs explain [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/blob/master/README.md#bashexeminttyexe-aliases)