# How make cmder runs .sh files on Windows 10?

Tags: bash, cmder

I'm using commander to do a lot of job on Windows. My only problem is that I'm not able to run `.sh` files.

[image]

The image above says that there is no program associated to run `.sh` extension.

My workaround is to type `bash file.sh` But I rather to do not type `bash` everytume.

Comment: Does it work if you put `#!/bin/bash` as first line in your script?

Comment: does not works.

Comment: Looks like associating `.sh` files with `bash` won't work. I am also on windows and my git-bash is associated to `.sh` files. When I run `.\file.sh` it opens git-bash in separate window, executes the script and immediately closes the window. I believe that the best you can do is what this guy proposed https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317535/7411306.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to run the below command to execute shell scripts on cmder windows 10.

```
sh test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way is just to open a new tab (Ctrl + T) and switch to `{bash::mintty as Admin}`. Then you just run your scripts as usual `./test.sh`